# This developer add-on is restricted by policies within your organization

Tags: google-workspace, gmail-addons

I'm trying to test a gmail add-on within my G-Suite organization. Gmail reports me the message above, even if the developer add-on is developed by the same google account within my G-Suite organization I am trying to install it.

What policies would prevent the installation of a developer add-on on gmail.

In the G-Suite admin console I have configured Apps/Marketplace apps/Settings for Marketplace apps/Manage access to apps/ as "Allow useres to install any application from G-Suite Marketplace."

Whatelse must be verified in order to allow an user from G-Suite domain to use its own developed add-on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be able to get to the security settings.

There are basically 3 areas of concern:

- Enable users to install Add-ons
- Enable API's that Apps Script will use
- Whitelist Apps Script projects - https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227#

Navigate to the Admin home page:
https://admin.google.com/AdminHome

### Enable API's that Apps Script will use

From the admin home page, you will see lots of tiles with names like:

- Users
- Company Profile
- Billing
- Apps
- Security - Manage security features

Click the "Security" tile if it is available.
If you don't see the "Security" tile, then try using the link below:

Link to Security:
https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#SecuritySettings:

Click "API Access"

Make sure that GMail is enabled.

In addition, you can get a list of installed and trusted apps by scrolling to the bottom of the list and clicking the link.

If one or more API scopes have been disabled across G Suite services, and you don't want to give broad access, then you can whitelist individual projects.  In order to whitelist an individual Apps Script project, you will need the App ID.

If the add-on is already installed, then you can get the App Id, from the list of installed apps.  Use the link below to go to the installed apps page:  https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#Oauth2ScopeManagement:subtab=installed

In the list of installed apps, there is a column for App Ids.  Look for the add-on name in column one, then triple click the App Id field to highlight the App Id.  Copy the App Id.  You will paste this App Id into the new Trusted App setting.  If the add-on is not already installed, and users aren’t allowed to install the add-on, then you’ll need to get the App Id from the developer.

### Enable email in your domain

The administrator has the option of controlling services from 3 categories:

- Everyone
- Groups - https://support.google.com/a/answer/9050643?hl=en
- Organizational units

The admin can turn off GMail service for everyone in the organization.  If GMail service is turned off for everyone in the entire organization, but you want to enable GMail for specific people or groups of people, then the admin will need to set up Groups or Organizational Units.

From the main admin page, go into:  Apps -> GSuite  - https://admin.google.com/ac/appslist/core

For information about how to use groups see the following link:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9050643?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Sandy. I had already configured all this steps you described above. Today, I went back to the account to check and surprisingly the add-ons were available to the user.
It looks like it had taken almost 48 hours to have the changes reflected to the user. 
This is the only reasonable reason I would give for the problem I was seeing yesterday.

Thanks for your prompt response.